# Inventories, Containers and Filters

Tags: c#, object-oriented, game, .net

Coming off a comment on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101584/entities-and-the-things-they-do), I figure it cannot hurt to post my `Inventory` work here as well.

Basically, I have `Item`, which is a base item, and then `Container`, which is a specialized item that has sub-items in it. The `Container` object, however, can be *filtered* to only permit (or restrict) certain items by some "property" `X`.

The `Container` objects can have *any number* of filters on them, restricting different things. For example, all `Container` objects have an `OversizeContainerFilter`, which essentially prevents the container from filling up over the maximum `Weight` it can hold. The `Inventory` `Container` also has an `ItemTypeContainerFilter` to restrict it to **only** be permitted to contain other `Container` items.

Now, this is actually a pretty complex portion of the setup. Essentially, an `Item` is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A base class for an item.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Item
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a unique <code>System.Guid</code> to represent the <see cref="Item"/> globally.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <code>string</code> of the description of the <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <code>string</code> of the name of the <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <code>float</code> weight for the <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual float Weight { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <see cref="SingleIcon"/> representing the icon image of the <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public SingleIcon Icon { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <code>List&lt;Guid&gt;></code> that represents the list of the <see cref="Material"/>s that make up this <see cref="Item"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Guid> Materials { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines how damaged the <see cref="Item"/> is.
    /// </summary>
    public ushort Wear { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines what <see cref="ItemType"/> the <see cref="Item"/> is. Must be overriden in derived classes.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get { return ItemType.None; } }
}
```

These are pretty simple, an `Item` has certain, base, properties.

Where it starts getting potentially murky is when `Container` objects come into play:

```
/// <summary>
/// The base interface for a container.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Container : Item, IList<Item>
{
    private List<Item> _items;
    private List<IDepositFilter> _filters;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum weight the <see cref="Container"/> can hold.
    /// </summary>
    public float MaxWeight { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the preference of the <see cref="Container"/>. Lower values mean a higher preference.
    /// </summary>
    public byte Preference { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns <see cref="ItemType.Container"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed override ItemType ItemType { get { return ItemType.Container; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="Item.Weight"/> of the <see cref="Container"/> and of all <see cref="Item"/> objects within the <see cref="Container"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed override float Weight { get { float totalWeight = base.Weight; foreach (Item item in _items) { totalWeight += item.Weight; } return totalWeight; } set { base.Weight = value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of a <see cref="Container"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    public Container()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
        _filters = new List<IDepositFilter>();

        _filters.Add(new OversizeContainerFilter());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of <see cref="IDepositFilter"/> objects associated with the current <see cref="Container"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public List<IDepositFilter> Filters { get { return _filters; } }

    public bool CanAddItem(Item item)
    {
        foreach (var filter in Filters)
        {
            if (!filter.IsAllowed(this, item))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int IndexOf(Item item) { return _items.IndexOf(item); }

    public void Insert(int index, Item item)
    {
        if (!CanAddItem(item))
            throw new ItemNotAllowedException();

        _items.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) { _itemsRemoveAt(index); }

    public Item this[int index] { get { return _items[index]; } set { _items[index] = value; } }

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        if (!CanAddItem(item))
            throw new ItemNotAllowedException();

        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() { _items.Clear(); }

    public bool Contains(Item item) { return _items.Contains(item); }

    public void CopyTo(Item[] array, int arrayIndex) { _Items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); }

    public int Count { get { return _items.Count; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public bool Remove(Item item) { return _items.Remove(item); }

    IEnumerator<Item> IEnumerable<Item>.GetEnumerator() { return _items.GetEnumerator(); }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return _items.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

A `Container` can hold other `Item` objects, but only if they meet the `IDepositFilter` requirements:

```
public interface IDepositFilter
{
    bool IsAllowed(Container destination, Item item);
}
```

Examples of some `IDepositFilter` restrictions:

```
public class DefaultContainerFilter : IDepositFilter
{
    public bool IsAllowed(Container destination, Item item)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class ItemTypeContainerFilter : IDepositFilter
{
    private List<ItemType> _allowTypes;
    private List<ItemType> _blockTypes;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="ItemTypeContainerFilter"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allowTypes">The <see cref="ItemType"/> enumeration values that should be explicitly allowed. If this is not an empty list, then only these types are permitted.</param>
    /// <param name="blockTypes">The <see cref="ItemType"/> enumeration values that should be explicitly blocked. If this is not an empty list, then these types are disallowed.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If neither parameters are specified, then all <see cref="ItemType"/> enumeration values are blocked. If both are specified, then items in the allow list take priority.
    /// </remarks>
    public ItemTypeContainerFilter(List<ItemType> allowTypes, List<ItemType> blockTypes)
    {
        _allowTypes = allowTypes;
        _blockTypes = blockTypes;
    }

    public bool IsAllowed(Container destination, Item item)
    {
        if (_allowTypes != null && _allowTypes.Contains(item.ItemType))
            return true;

        if (_blockTypes != null && _blockTypes.Contains(item.ItemType))
            return false;

        if (_allowTypes != null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}

public class OversizeContainerFilter : IDepositFilter
{
    public bool IsAllowed(Container destination, Item item)
    {
        return destination.MaxWeight >= (item.Weight + destination.Weight);
    }
}
```

And lastly, the `Inventory`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a collection of <see cref="Container"/> objects owned by an <see cref="Actor"/>.
/// </summary>
public class Inventory : Container
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="Inventory"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public Inventory() : base()
    {
        Filters.Add(new ItemTypeContainerFilter(new List<ItemType> { ItemType.Container }, null));
    }
}
```

Note: after posting this I did `_camelCase` all the `private` variables that were `_PascalCase`.

Comment: For the properties that do a simple `get` and `set`, I don't think you need _backingVariable.  Instead you could just use something like `public string Name { get; set; }`, and ditch the `_name`.

Comment: @RickDavin Yeah, this was before I was comfortable with auto-implemented properties. You should post that as an answer for the +1! :)

Comment: No big deal.  Not really a point grub.  Last time I did it for you on `DateTime.UtcNow` was not for points but because I had relevant links and explanatory text that could benefit others.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your `Container` class, the indexer probably should be read only.  The `Add` and `Insert` methods have `CanAddItem` checks.  But this line:

`public Item this[int index] { get { return _Items[index]; } set { _Items[index] = value; } }`

could allow someone to replace the value with an item that fails the `CanAddItem` check.  I wouldn't suggest adding extra checks in the setter.  It really should be a readonly property.

```
public Item this[int index] { get { return _Items[index]; } }
```

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't even notice that. Good find! :)